# Error while using 'new' command while creating a project in gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

[image: This]is the error I get while I'm trying to get a new starter project in gatsby.
`node version: v14.4.0`
`npm version: 6.14.5`
`gatsby version: 2.4.17`
Also, the error is the same while working with recent gatsby version.
Please help or suggest something.

Answer (score 1):

> `git` is not recognized as an internal or external command

You need to install git.
it seems you are using windows so [install git on windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win)

You may need to close the `cmd` and open it again in order to use `git`.

Since windows may not automatically add `git` to your PATH environment variables:

1. Open Git Bash which should have been installed along with Git if you downloaded the correct installer.
2. Type the command you want to run, it should start with git.
3. Press enter.

Comment: Yes, I thought that this should be an issue. So I did install git but for no use.

Comment: have you restart the terminal/cmd?